# Classify the set $\{(x,y,z):f(x,y,z)=0, \nabla f=0\}$, where $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 3.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree at most 2. Observe the following set:
$$S=\{(x,y) : f(x,y)=0 ,\; \partial_{x}f(x,y)=0,\; \partial_{y}f(x,y)=0  \}.$$
Note that this set is the intersection of zeros of $f$ and critical points of $f$. One may see that $S$ is finite union of points or a line. This case is easy.

I'm interested in the generalization of this problem. More precisely, let $f(x,y,z)$ be a nonzero polynomial of degree at most $3$. Consider the following set:
$$S=\{(x,y,z): f(x,y,z)=0,\; \nabla f(x,y,z)=0 \}. $$
I want to classify the set $S$.

If $f=x^3$, then $S$ is a hyperplane.

If $f=x^2+y^2+z^2$, then $S$ is finite union of points.

If $f=x^2+y^2$, then $S$ is a 1-dimensional surface.

It seems to make sense that $S$ is a hyperplane or finite union of points or a 1-dimensional surface. But I don't know how to attack this problem. Any comments will be welcomed.

Comment: What is a $1$-dimensional surface?

Comment: @JackLee Lee Basically, I meant that a 1-dimensional surface is a 1-dimensional regular submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$.(For example, a line or an ellipse) But a slight modification may be possible.